# FOR..NEXT loop in T4 (VB)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4

(im using MVC4 VB). I want a FOR .. NEXT loop in my T4 "List.tt" template.
The first line of that template is:

```
<#@ template language="VB" HostSpecific="True" #>
```

This gives no syntax errors:

```
<# 
for i = i to 10 
 writeline(i) 
next 
#>
```

but that does not work: "Error  4   Compiling transformation: 'i' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

So it's less VB then i expected...
Do you know the correct syntax and/or a website with *full* T4 documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

As the error says. You have to declare the variable

#### Sample

```
<# 
Dim i As Integer
for i = 0 to 10 
   writeline(i) 
next 
#>
```

#### More Information

- [Code Generation Using T4 Templates](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/557_Code_Generation_Using_T4_Templates.aspx)
- [Loops in VB.NET](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/language/loops.aspx)

Comment: after that i got "The 'ReferencedAssemblies' property cannot contain null or empty strings." i more or less started all over with an empty project and yes: this works now. i like VS a lot, but with a MVC project i often need to debug/reopen the project in order to get things right.

Comment: in addition to this: i added this line: <#@ import namespace=”Microsoft.VisualBasic” #>   after that T4 learned VB